# How to replace event handler when button is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, onclick

I have a situation where I have to replace all unauthorized controls in My UI from hidden state to disabled. Add a tooltip with un authorized text. Click the control to see unauthorized text.

I am able to update code but blocked at one point where I have to stop firing event on the control.
At the same time I have to show an alert on click of the event. How can I do this?

[My trails are here in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvger3tg/3/)

Problem:
I have [clickdisabled = disable] click function which need to be called if control is disabled.
But at the same time on the control I have  onclick="SearchDetails(); called which is throwing an error.

```
<input id="btnSearch" type="button" name="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="SearchDetails();return false;" title="search" clickDisabled=disable />

//Add title to all disabled items in project
$('[clickdisabled=disable]').attr("title", "You are not authorized to perform this action.");

//  Show unauthorized error on click of disabled control
$('[clickdisabled = disable]').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("title"));
});
```

Comment: To be sure I understand you, you want to replace the `SearchDetails()` method with another event handler when the button is disabled?

Comment: Correct. But I want his replacement to be generic for all files in the project. So I am trying to make disabled element events on priority and got struck on how to implement this.

Comment: I assume that you also want to revert the action so that `SearchDetails()` becomes the event handler again when the button is re-enabled?

Comment: absolutely correct threed.

Comment: Please stay tuned...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vvger3tg/6/

Comment: click event is not fired with the fiddle example.

Comment: ...and we're back.  Check my answer below; see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting situations when the functions are not available, you could check if they exist before calling them:

```
<input id="btnSearch" type="button" name="btnSearch" value="Search" 
onclick="if (typeof(SearchDetails) === typeof(Function)) SearchDetails();"
 title="search" clickDisabled=disable />
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ak9gsy0h/)

Comment: I tried removing attribute clickDisabled=disable and it is not calling SearchDetails function. http://jsfiddle.net/ak9gsy0h/1/

Comment: you have to uncomment the second line on the JS to see it working when the function is defined

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is keep track of both your normal onclick event handler and disabled onclick event handler.  When you disable your button, remove the normal onclick event handler and add your disabled onclick event handler.  When you re-enable the button, remove the disabled onclick event handler, and add the normal event handler back.  You can do this with the jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) events (see the example below).

```js
function onNormalClick(e){
    alert('This is the default test button functionality.');
}
function onDisabledClick(e){
        alert('This button is disabled.');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();    
}
function disableButtons(selector){
    $(selector).css('color', '#888');
    $(selector).off('click', onNormalClick);
    $(selector).on('click', onDisabledClick);
}
function enableButtons(selector){
    $(selector).css('color', '#000');
    $(selector).off('click', onDisabledClick);
    $(selector).on('click', onNormalClick);
}
               
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test').on('click', onNormalClick);
    $('#disabler').click(function(){
        disableButtons('.test');
    });
    $('#enabler').click(function(){
        enableButtons('.test');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='test'>Test</button>
<hr/>
<button id=disabler>Disable</button>
<button id=enabler>Enable</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent the default handling like this:

```
var button = $('#your_button_id');
button.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Your alert message for the user");
});
```

Comment: Minato than you so much for your time. But the code you provided did not work for me. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vvger3tg/4/